# Weight as tension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

Tension problems are very simple, but, in some of them, there is a singular case:

[image]

In this one, to get the values of the tensions, we take into account only three forces: the weight becomes another tension, the third tension with a value of 500 Newtons. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the weight that becomes a third tension. The third tension is the tension in the vertical wire. So you actually have three tensions balancing at the common point of the three wires. It just happens that the mgnitude of the tension in the vertical wire is equal (in magnitude) to the weight. This equality results from the equilibrium condition for the block (50 kg mass). There are two forces on the block: its weight and the vertical tension.